# How to duplicate (copy) a row keeping the protected ranges

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google sheets, I have a sheet in which there is a group of lines that duplicate a template line.
Within the template line I have protected cells or ranges of cells **that only I can modify**.

I want the other users to be able to add copies of the template line to the group using a button that triggers a script.
At the moment the script, does the copy of the template line correctly but the ranges that were protected in the template or no longer protected in the copy.

**Here is the script:**

```
function AddParticipant(){
  var spreadsheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var thisSheet=spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()
  var sourceRange=thisSheet.getRange(7,1,1,thisSheet.getMaxColumns()).activate()

  //the ◇ char is the place before which the copy must be inserted
  var testCol= thisSheet.getRange(1,2,thisSheet.getMaxRows()).getValues()

  var pos=0
  for (var i=0;i<testCol.length;i++){
    if (testCol[i] == "◇"){
      break
    }
    pos=i+2
  }
 var destRange=thisSheet.getRange(pos,1).activate()
 thisSheet.insertRowsBefore(thisSheet.getActiveRange().getRow(),1)
 sourceRange.copyTo(destRange,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL,false)
}
```

Is it possible to keep the protected ranges with the same protection in the copy?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `template line` and `keep the protected ranges with the same protection in the copy`. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Thank you for you attention. template line means a model that can be copied several times . After copy the other users can modify some cells in the copy but some others cells are protected to prevent them to be changed. I want the copy to keep theses cells protected as they are in the model.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. For example, in order to help to understand your question, can you provide your current script? I would like to try to correctly understand your question by confirming your current script.

Comment: I just added the script to the initial post

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your showing script and your question, I understood your situation as follows.

- When you run `AddParticipant`, you want to copy row 7 to the destination row of the same sheet.
- The destination rows are protected. By this, when you who is the owner of Spreadsheet run the script, no error occurs. But, when a user who is not the owner runs the script, an error occurs because of the protected range.
- You want to make users run the script without the error even when the destination range is protected.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

In order to edit the protected range with the script by users who are not the owner of the Spreadsheet, I think that when the script is run as the owner of the Spreadsheet, no error occurs.

In order to achieve this, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

1. The installable OnEdit trigger is used. When the installable OnEdit trigger is used, the script can be run by the owner.
2. The Web Apps is used. When Web Apps is used, the script can be run by the owner.

#### Pattern 1: Use installale OnEdit trigger

Unfortunately, in this case, the button on the Spreadsheet cannot be used. Because, when the script is run by clicking a button on Spreadsheet, the script is run by each user. So, in order to use this pattern, please replace the button with a checkbox. In this pattern, the checkbox is used as the button for executing the script.

For example, please insert a checkbox to "A1". By this, when the checkbox is checked, the script is run. The modified script is as follows.

And, please install the OnEdit trigger to `installedOnEdit`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#manage_triggers_manually) By this, when the checkbox is checked, the script is run.

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  const { range } = e;
  if (range.getA1Notation() != "A1" || !range.isChecked()) return;
  AddParticipant();
  range.uncheck()
}

function AddParticipant() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var thisSheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var sourceRange = thisSheet.getRange(7, 1, 1, thisSheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  //the ◇ char is the place before wich the copy must be inserted
  var testCol = thisSheet.getRange(1, 2, thisSheet.getMaxRows()).getValues();
  var pos = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < testCol.length; i++) {
    if (testCol[i] == "◇") {
      break;
    }
    pos = i + 2;
  }
  var destRange = thisSheet.getRange(pos, 1).activate();
  thisSheet.insertRowsBefore(thisSheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  sourceRange.copyTo(destRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
}
```

- When the checkbox of "A1" is checked, `AddParticipant()` is run.

#### Pattern 2: Use Web Apps

In this pattern, your button on the Spreadsheet can be used. The script is run through the Web Apps. In order to use this, please do the following flow.

##### 1. Deploy Web Apps.

The detailed information can be seen in [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app).

Please set this using the new IDE of the script editor.

1. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "New deployment".
2. Please click "Select type" -> "Web App".
3. Please input the information about the Web App in the fields under "Deployment configuration".
4. Please select **"Me"** for **"Execute as"**.
5. Please select **"Anyone with Google account"** for **"Who has access to the app:"**.
6. Please click "Deploy" button.
7. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "Test deployments".
8. Copy Web Apps URL. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`. This URL is used with Python script.

##### 2. Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor. And, please set your Web Apps URL to `const webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev";`.

```js
const doGet = _ => AddParticipant(true);

function AddParticipant(e) {
  if (!e) {
    const webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev"; // Please set your Web Apps URL.
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(webAppsUrl, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
    return;
  }
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var thisSheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var sourceRange = thisSheet.getRange(7, 1, 1, thisSheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  //the ◇ char is the place before wich the copy must be inserted
  var testCol = thisSheet.getRange(1, 2, thisSheet.getMaxRows()).getValues();
  var pos = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < testCol.length; i++) {
    if (testCol[i] == "◇") {
      break;
    }
    pos = i + 2;
  }
  var destRange = thisSheet.getRange(pos, 1).activate();
  thisSheet.insertRowsBefore(thisSheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  sourceRange.copyTo(destRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
}

// ### Please don't remove the following comment line.
// DriveApp.getFiles(); // This comment line is used for automatically detecting a scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly". This scope is used for requesting Web Apps.
// ###
```

##### 3. Testing.

When you click the button assigned with `AddParticipant`, the script is run. And, the script is run by Web Apps. By this, when the users who are not the owner of Spreadsheet are running the script, the script is run.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: Thank you for your time and your detailed explanation. I am new to google sheets and, thanks to you, I discover new things. I will give a try to them soon. Nevertheless you initial description of the situation is not exact. For explanation, lets call line 7 the source  and the copied line destination. Even using the macro myself, the destination  loses its protected cells, but I can include some lines in the script to reset the protection. Contrarily to what you say, an other user can run the macro but the resetting of the protection doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @Meaulnes Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the issue of my answer from your reply. Can I ask you about the details of it? When my answer was not useful for your situation, I have to apologize.

Comment: Please don't mind. I tried to deploy Web App but it  failed as after step 6 ("Please click Deploy Button") it asks me for autorization. After clicking the Autorize access button and selecting my account, it tells me that Google has not verified this App. From this point I cannot go any further.

Comment: I could go further and allow the app but now the script exit from the initial test (if (!e))

Comment: By the way, what is the Install button at the bottom of the Test Deployments windows for? I used it and now it works. The trouble is that I do not understand what I am doing.

Comment: @Meaulnes Thank you for replying. From `By the way, what is the Install button at the bottom of the Test Deployments windows for? I used it and now it works. The trouble is that I do not understand what I am doing.`, I think that "Install button" is for using to Google Workspace add-on. When you can see the test deployments for Web Apps by selecting only "Web Apps" at "Select type". By the way, I'm not sure whether your question was resolved. If my answer was not useful, please tell me. I have to apologize.

Comment: @Meaulnes By the way, from `I tried to deploy Web App`, you don't use pattern 1. Is my understanding correct? And, from `now it works`, your issue was resolved by pattern 2. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes I am using pattern 2. It works but I am not sure my issue is completely resolved. For example, If I make a copy of the sheet and call the script in the new sheet, it does the job in the original sheet, while an other script (that is not deployed as Web App) works in the sheet from which I launch it. Another question is should I repeat this process for all my macros. I feel you are very clever at this subject and I would like to be able to discuss with you by another way, mail or chat as it is suggested just above this comment.

Comment: @Meaulnes Thank you for replying. From `I am using pattern 2. It works`, I understand that your issue was resolved. About your new questions, I would like to support you. But your issues are new issues. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by a comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, we can think of it. At that time, [please close this question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I have created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77352920/why-my-deployed-script-acts-in-a-sheet-different-from-the-active-sheet)

Comment: @Meaulnes Thank you for your response. I will check your new question.