# Why my deployed script acts in a sheet different from the active sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This question is a sequel to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77345055/how-to-duplicate-copy-a-row-keeping-the-protected-ranges).

I have a sheet with 2 macros (scripts). One has been deployed as WebApp script to resolve an issue about protections when used by other users (see post referenced above) and one that is an ordinary script.

The sheet I use is intended to be used as a template (model) for other sheets produced by duplication of the template.
Thus I duplicated my original sheet.
The ordinary macro (the one that is not deployed as WebApp script) works fine in both the original sheet and the copy.
The deployed script copy a template line at the bottom of existing lines.
The deployed script works normally in the original sheet but when triggered from the copy sheet it does its work not in the copy sheet but into the original sheet.
How to make this script work in the active sheet? In other word, when I trigger the macro from the duplicated sheet, I want it to add a line in this sheet and in this sheet only.

The script is visible [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WHp9MZktlshECu12mhTiEVDoVWiA9P18oOttRReNCek/edit)

Comment: Have you tried using [openbyID](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)? This is to ensure that the script will work on the specific sheet that you want.

Comment: From your question, I thought that I understood your expected result. When a Google Apps Script project including Web Apps is copied, the script of Web Apps is copied. But, the Web Apps is required to be deployed in the copied Google Apps Script project. And, the deployment ID is different from the original one. So, it is required to copy and paste the Web Apps URL again.

Comment: For example, when the method for using the checkbox as a button for executing the script is used (Pattern 1 of my answer to your previous question), the installable trigger can be installed from the outside of the copied Spreadsheet. So, in that case, a script for achieving this can be created.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your help. I am a bit confused as I don't clearly understand your point. At first I created a script AddParticipant (now renamed AddNewParticipant) in the Macro script editor of the Spreadsheet. Then I changed this script according to your advice and deployed it as explained. At this time I had only one sheet (let's call it sheet1)  in the Spreadsheet. Then I duplicated the sheet as sheet2. The button (drawing) in the sheet1 that was assigned the AddNewParticipant script was copied into the sheet2 and remained assigned to script AddNewParticipant.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your question, I thought that you might have wanted to copy a Google Spreadsheet as another Google Spreadsheet. From `Then I duplicated the sheet as sheet2.`, in this case, you want to copy one of the sheets in a Google Spreadsheet, and you want to achieve the same situation with the copied sheet using the same script in the same Google Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I never copied a Web App or a Web script. I just want my users (who are not supposed to be IT people) to be able to replicate the original sheet, pulling with each copy the attached scripts and not ask them to accomplish complex tasks .

Comment: By the way assigning the button the doGet script instead of AddNewParticipant resolve the problem but doing this, I am faced with a new problem : how to create an other macro as I can use doGet only one time in a Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tanaike. I think our comment are mixed. Yes I want to achieve the same situation with the copied sheet using the same script in the same Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, when one of the sheets is copied, the copied sheet has the same button assigned with `AddParticipant` (Now, the function name has been changed to `AddNewParticipant `?)?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes I changed the name because I had to restart from scratch . And yes the assignation of the button is the same in the copy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255727/discussion-between-meaulnes-and-tanaike).

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Thank you again. I cannot say as I don't see the modified script. Where is it ?

Comment: Sorry. I can see it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have a Google Spreadsheet including a script of "Pattern 2" in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77349113/7108653).
- When one of the sheets in the Google Spreadsheet, you want to use the script by clicking the button on the copied sheet.
- You changed the function name from `AddParticipant` to `AddNewParticipant`.

In this case, how about the following modification?

In this modification, the specific sheet is used by sending the active sheet name to Web Apps.

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set your Web Apps URL. You can see the method for deploying Web Apps at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77349113/7108653).

**In this modification, it is supposed that the function `AddNewParticipant` is assigned to the button on the sheet. Please be careful about this.**

```js
const doGet = e => AddNewParticipant(e);

function AddNewParticipant(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  if (!e) {
    const webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev"; // Please set your Web Apps URL.
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(`${webAppsUrl}?sheetName=${ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName()}`, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
    return;
  }
  var thisSheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.sheetName);
  var sourceRange = thisSheet.getRange(7, 1, 1, thisSheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  //the ◇ char is the place before wich the copy must be inserted
  var testCol = thisSheet.getRange(1, 2, thisSheet.getMaxRows()).getValues();
  var pos = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < testCol.length; i++) {
    if (testCol[i] == "◇") {
      break;
    }
    pos = i + 2;
  }
  var destRange = thisSheet.getRange(pos, 1).activate();
  thisSheet.insertRowsBefore(thisSheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  sourceRange.copyTo(destRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
}

// ### Please don't remove the following comment line.
// DriveApp.getFiles(); // This comment line is used for automatically detecting a scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly". This scope is used for requesting Web Apps.
// ###
```

- When the function `AddNewParticipant` is run by clicking a button on the sheet, the sheet name of the active sheet is retrieved, and the sheet name is sent to Web Apps. And, in the Web Apps, the sheet of the retrieved sheet name is used. By this, the sheet clicked the button is used.

Comment: @Thank you for this proposal. It doesn't work. When the button is clicked in sheet1 or sheet2 nothing happens.  To know more I added logs. Log1: just as the first statement in function AddNewParticipant Logger.log(e). Log2: just before return in the if bloc Logger.Log(' End of if test')). Log3: just after the closing curly brace of the if bloc Logger.log('Entering the script'). The execution log is Notice Execution started / Info: null / info: End of if test / Notice: Execution completed. According to the logs, it seems that e is null and that the script is never entered.

Comment: I present you my apologies. Your script is working. As I made amendments in my script since our first conversation I didn't want to rewrite all and just corrected the statements that had to be corrected. Unfortunately I made a mistake. It is good now. Nevertheless I am facing a new problem : What if I want to use an other macro that now copies columns with protected ranges instead of rows? How to differentiate the 2 button clics ? I hope you understand my question if not ask me for more clarity.

Comment: I open a new question for this

Comment: [New question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77356804/how-to-have-several-macros-using-each-one-a-web-app-script)

Comment: @Meaulnes Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too. I will check your new question.