# How to have several macros using each one a Web App script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This question is a sequel to 2 other questions : [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77345055/how-to-duplicate-copy-a-row-keeping-the-protected-ranges) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77352920/why-my-deployed-script-acts-in-a-sheet-different-from-the-active-sheet).
In a SpreadsheetApp I need a template sheet with several macros. Each macro is triggered by a click on a button (a drawing that is assigned a macro). The macros copy paste rows or columns that have protected areas. When used by the owner the protections that are lost during the copy paste can be restored, but when used by an other user they cannot be restored.

A solution was found for this for one macro see First question referenced above.

In a second time, a problem arose when using a copy of the original sheet as the macro triggered from the second sheet did its work into the first sheet.

Again, a solution was found for this for one macro (see Second question referenced above).

Now I am facing a new problem. I want to have several macros using the same mechanism but I cannot reproduce an equivalent script because I have an error : identifier doGet has already been declared !

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Now I am facing a new problem. I want to have several macros using the same mechanism but I cannot reproduce an equivalent script because I have an error : identifier doGet has already been declared !`. Can I ask you about the details of your current issue and your goal? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike. Thank you for answering. At the moment, thanks to your help we have a macro that is triggered by a click on a button. This macro copy-pastes a row at the bottom of a suite of rows. It works in both sheet 1 and sheet 2 that is a copy of sheet1. So far so good!  ...

Comment: Now I want to create a second macro that instead of copying a row should copy columns. But no matter what the macro does. This second macro needs also to be a Web App script for the same reasons we turned the first one into a Web App script. How can I do this as I cannot have 2 doGet in the same project (SpreadSheet)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply, I cannot still imagine your expected result. Can you provide the detils of `Now I want to create a second macro that instead of copying a row should copy columns.`? Where column do you want to copy to where cell? Unfortunately, I cannot imagine what you want to do. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Please do not apologize as you greatly help me. Thanks again for this. I will do my best to make me understood. First, I have a working macro in my Spreadsheet. But I need to create more macros doing various things but in a Spreadsheet we can only have one doGet function. Thus I need to use the same doGet for all the macros. Each macro must be triggered by a different button a use a Web App Script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? Or, can you provide your script of `Now I want to create a second macro that instead of copying a row should copy columns.`?

Comment: It is not a matter of what situation I start from or ends to, it the necessity to write other macros similar to the first we managed to do together whatever the macros do.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MsyxBHT_MaR2lbylEa8BBiy1dWw-Z9kl3D6cbx7URaQ/edit) you can see the macro that presently works but that should also be turned to a Web App Script as when an other user triggers it it doesn't restore the protected ranges.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vH0e7ZaNas06ZJPfcDQaCPZNmbHXxtaYJgY5MUPI-MA/edit) is the previous script I tried to turn into a deployed Web App. When I try to run it, I get this error : SyntaxError: Identifier 'doGet' has already been declared. I hope you could help me.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot still imagine your expected result. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I really apologize for my poor English skill again. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly imagine your expected result from your replies, I would like to think of a solution. If you can give me a time to understand your question, I'm glad. Can you give me a time to do it?

Comment: Thank you again for your time and help. Of course I can give you time to understand my question. As I told you what the macros do is not important the problem is to have more than one when using Web App scripts because we cannot write const doGet = e => function1(e) and then, in another script,  const doGet =e => function2(e). I hope you could understand my point.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that when I can correctly understand your question, I can propose an answer. But, unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. I need time to understand your question, now. I deeply apologize for this situation. I think that I need to reflect on my poor English skill.

Comment: Don't worry to much. I understand. My wife is Japanese and very often we have difficulties to communicate on complex subjects. This is due to the fact that our languages and ways of thinking are very different. I only hope you will be able to understand and find a solution because i am stuck on this now. Sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a solution I would never have found without the invaluable help of Tanaike. Many thanks to him again.

In fact my mistake was that I did not fully understand the mechanism of Web App scripts.
I was writting 2 files. The first one like this:

```
const doGet = e => AddNewParticipant(e)   
function AddNewParticipant(e){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    if (!e) {
        const webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzDV97QE4JL.../dev"; // Please set your Web Apps URL.
        UrlFetchApp.fetch(`${webAppsUrl}?sheetName=${ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName()}&what=Activity`, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
    return;
    }

  var thisSheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.sheetName)
   //DO OTHER STUFF HERE
}
```

and the second one like this:

```
const doGet = e => AddPayingActivity(e)   
function AddPayingActivity(e){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    if (!e) {
        const webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzDV9.../dev"; // Please set your Web Apps URL.
        UrlFetchApp.fetch(`${webAppsUrl}?sheetName=${ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName()}`, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
    return;
    }

  var thisSheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.sheetName)
   //DO OTHER STUFF HERE
}
```

Each of these file was deployed thus I had 2 differents urls. More over the macros failed because I also had twice the statement

```
const doGet = e => something(e)
```

**The solution was to have only one file, like this:**

```
const doGet = e => myMacros(e)

function myMacros(e){
  switch (e.parameter.what){
    case "Participant":
      Logger.log('case is Participant')
       AddNewParticipant(e)
       break
    case "Activity":
      Logger.log('case is Activity')
      AddPayingActivity(e)
      break
    default:
      Logger.log('Exiting with no selection')
  }
}

function AddPayingActivity(e){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    Logger.log('entering the script from myMacros')
    if (!e) {
      const webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzDV97QE4JL2yI1kTDv2fGTXc7hfDdsFEv1LCs74LVe/dev"; // Please set your Web Apps URL.
      UrlFetchApp.fetch(`${webAppsUrl}?sheetName=${ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName()}&what=Activity`, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
      Logger.log('Exit the first if test bloc')
      return;
  }

  var thisSheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.sheetName)
  //DO OTHER STUFF HERE

};

function AddNewParticipant(e){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

    if (!e) {
    const webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzDV97QE4JL2yI1kTDv2fGTXc7hfDdsFEv1LCs74LVe/dev"; // Please set your Web Apps URL.
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(`${webAppsUrl}?sheetName=${ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName()}&what=Participant`, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
    return;
  }
  var thisSheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.sheetName)
   //DO OTHER STUFF HERE
}
// ### Please don't remove the following comment line.
// DriveApp.getFiles(); // This comment line is used for automatically detecting a scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly". This scope is used for requesting Web Apps.
// ###
```

This way I have only one doGet statement and only one url. I distinguish the macros using an additional parameter (what) in the url.