# How to Allow Restricted Users to Log Data in Protected Google Sheets via Apps Script Sidebar?

Tags: javascript, html

I've developed a Google Sheets application with a custom sidebar for users to log data into a protected sheet ("Progress Log Sheet"). The sidebar is implemented in HTML (Page.html) and interacts with Google Apps Script (Log Enter.gs). I need to restrict certain users from manually editing the sheet while allowing them to submit data through the sidebar.

Users with restricted access to the "Progress Log Sheet" are unable to use the sidebar to log data because they don't have edit access to the sheet. I need a way to allow these users to submit data through the sidebar without granting them direct edit access to the sheet.

All users on my spreadsheet are on a Google Workspace domain. Not sure if this information may be of any help.

## Log Enter.gs:

```
function openSidebar() {
    var lists = fetchDataLists();
    Logger.log(lists);
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page');
    html.names = lists.names;
    html.schools = lists.schools;
    html.processes = lists.processes;
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html.evaluate().setTitle('Production Log Entry').setWidth(300));
}

function fetchDataLists() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var names = ss.getSheetByName("Progress Log Sheet").getRange("N7:N").getValues().flat().filter(String);
    var schools = ss.getSheetByName("23-24 COMPOSITES").getRange("A2:A").getValues().flat().filter(String);
    var processes = ["Filtering", "First Correction", "Double Check", "Ripping"];

    schools.sort(); // Add this line to sort the schools array

    return {names: names, schools: schools, processes: processes};
}

function logDataFromSidebar(data) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Progress Log Sheet");
    var name = data.name;
    var school = data.school;
    var process = data.process;
    var classCount = data.classCount;
    var startTime = data.startTime;
    var endTime = data.endTime;
    var notes = data.notes;

    var logs = sheet.getRange("B7:I" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var duplicateFound = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < logs.length; i++) {
        if (logs[i][2] === school && logs[i][3] === process) {
            duplicateFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (name !== "" && school !== "" && process !== "" && !duplicateFound) {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var utcDate = new Date(currentDate.toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles" }));
        var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(utcDate, "GMT-7", "MM/dd/yy");
        var formattedTime = Utilities.formatDate(utcDate, "GMT-7", "h:mm:ss a");

        // Use adjustedDuration if available, otherwise calculate from startTime and endTime
        var totalMinutes = data.adjustedDuration !== undefined ? data.adjustedDuration : getMinutesFromTime(endTime) - getMinutesFromTime(startTime);

        sheet.appendRow(["", name, school, process, classCount, startTime, endTime, notes, formattedDate, formattedTime, totalMinutes]);

        // Call updateBreakType at the end
        updateBreakType();
    } else {
        if (name === "") {
            SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Name is missing. Please fill in the Name field.");
        } else if (school === "") {
            SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("School is missing. Please fill in the School field.");
        } else if (process === "") {
            SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Process is missing. Please fill in the Process field.");
        } else if (duplicateFound) {
            SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("A log with the same School and Process already exists.");
        }
    }
}

function getMinutesFromTime(time) {
    var timeComponents = time.split(":");
    var hours = parseInt(timeComponents[0]);
    var minutes = parseInt(timeComponents[1].split(" ")[0]);
    var meridiem = timeComponents[1].split(" ")[1].toUpperCase();

    if (meridiem === "PM" && hours !== 12) {
        hours += 12;
    } else if (meridiem === "AM" && hours === 12) {
        hours = 0;
    }

    return hours * 60 + minutes;
}

function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Composites')
        .addItem('Production Log Sheet', 'openSidebar')
        .addItem('Customer Service', 'openCustomerServiceUI')
        .addItem('Notes/Requests', 'openClientRequestsUI')
        .addToUi();
}
```

## Page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            padding: 15px;
        }
        h2 {
            color: #2C3E50;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #3498DB;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
        form {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        label {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .option-label {
            font-weight: normal;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            margin-bottom: 12px;
            position: relative;
        }
        select, textarea, input[type='text'] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 8px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #BDC3C7;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        input[type="checkbox"] {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        input[type="button"] {
            background-color: #3498DB;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
        }
        input[type="button"]:hover {
            background-color: #2980B9;
        }
        input[type="button"]:disabled {
            background-color: #AED6F1;
            cursor: not-allowed;
        }
        .break-lunch-options {
            margin-top: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #BDC3C7;
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
        }
        .break-lunch-options h3 {
            color: #3498DB;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .disabled-checkbox {
            opacity: 0.6;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        .space-above {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        /* Adjusting the checkbox alignment */
        .checkbox-inline {
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 24px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .checkbox-inline input[type='checkbox'] {
            position: absolute;
            opacity: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
        }
        .checkmark {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 20px;
            width: 20px;
            background-color: #eee;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Enter Log Data</h2>
    <form id="dataForm">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <select name="name">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Name</option>
        <? for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) { ?>
        <option value="<?= names[i] ?>"><?= names[i] ?></option>
        <? } ?>
    </select>
    <label>School:</label>
    <select name="school">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select School</option>
        <? for (var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) { ?>
        <option value="<?= schools[i] ?>"><?= schools[i] ?></option>
        <? } ?>
    </select>
    <label>Process:</label>
    <select name="process">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Process</option>
        <? for (var i = 0; i < processes.length; i++) { ?>
        <option value="<?= processes[i] ?>"><?= processes[i] ?></option>
        <? } ?>
    </select>
    <label>Class Count:</label>
    <input type="text" name="classCount">
    <label>Start Time:</label>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
        <select name="startHour" style="width: 32%;">
            <option value="" disabled selected>HH</option>
            <? for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) { ?>
            <option value="<?= i ?>"><?= i < 10 ? '0' + i : i ?></option>
            <? } ?>
        </select>
        <select name="startMinute" style="width: 32%;">
            <option value="" disabled selected>MM</option>
            <? for (var i = 0; i <= 59; i++) { ?>
            <option value="<?= i ?>"><?= i < 10 ? '0' + i : i ?></option>
            <? } ?>
        </select>
        <select name="startMeridiem" style="width: 32%;">
            <option value="AM">AM</option>
            <option value="PM">PM</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <label>End Time:</label>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
        <select name="endHour" style="width: 32%;">
            <option value="" disabled selected>HH</option>
            <? for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) { ?>
            <option value="<?= i ?>"><?= i < 10 ? '0' + i : i ?></option>
            <? } ?>
        </select>
        <select name="endMinute" style="width: 32%;">
            <option value="" disabled selected>MM</option>
            <? for (var i = 0; i <= 59; i++) { ?>
            <option value="<?= i ?>"><?= i < 10 ? '0' + i : i ?></option>
            <? } ?>
        </select>
        <select name="endMeridiem" style="width: 32%;">
            <option value="AM">AM</option>
            <option value="PM">PM</option>
        </select>
    </div>
        <div class="break-lunch-options">
            <h3>Breaks and Lunch</h3>
            <label class="option-label"><input type="checkbox" name="breakLunchOption" value="10" onclick="toggleCheckboxes(this, '10')"> 10 Minute Break</label>
            <label class="option-label"><input type="checkbox" name="breakLunchOption" value="30" onclick="toggleCheckboxes(this, '30')"> 30 Minute Lunch</label>
            <label class="option-label"><input type="checkbox" name="breakLunchOption" value="60" onclick="toggleCheckboxes(this, '60')"> 1 Hour Lunch</label>
        </div>
        <div class="space-above">
            <label>Notes:</label>
            <textarea name="notes"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Log Data" onclick="handleButtonClick(this)">
    </form>
    <script>

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            console.log("Names:", document.querySelector('[name="name"]').innerHTML);
            console.log("Schools:", document.querySelector('[name="school"]').innerHTML);
            console.log("Processes:", document.querySelector('[name="process"]').innerHTML);
        });

        function toggleCheckboxes(selectedCheckbox, value) {
            var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="breakLunchOption"]');
            checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
                if (checkbox.value !== value) {
                    checkbox.disabled = selectedCheckbox.checked;
                    checkbox.closest('.option-label').classList.toggle('disabled-checkbox', selectedCheckbox.checked);
                } else {
                    checkbox.disabled = false;
                }
            });
        }

function handleButtonClick(button) {
    var startHour = document.querySelector('[name="startHour"]').value;
    var startMinute = document.querySelector('[name="startMinute"]').value;
    var startMeridiem = document.querySelector('[name="startMeridiem"]').value;
    var endHour = document.querySelector('[name="endHour"]').value;
    var endMinute = document.querySelector('[name="endMinute"]').value;
    var endMeridiem = document.querySelector('[name="endMeridiem"]').value;

    var startTime = startHour + ':' + startMinute + ' ' + startMeridiem;
    var endTime = endHour + ':' + endMinute + ' ' + endMeridiem;

    var selectedBreak = document.querySelector('input[name="breakLunchOption"]:checked');

    if (!validateTimeSelection(startTime, endTime, selectedBreak)) {
        window.alert("The selected break or lunch option is not valid for the chosen time interval.");
        return;
    }

    button.disabled = true;

    logData().finally(() => {
        document.getElementById('dataForm').reset();
        toggleCheckboxes();
        button.disabled = false;
    });
}


function logData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var formData = {};
        var formElements = document.getElementById("dataForm").elements;
        for (var i = 0; i < formElements.length; i++) {
            if (formElements[i].type !== "button") {
                formData[formElements[i].name] = formElements[i].value;
            }
        }

        formData["startTime"] = formData["startHour"] + ":" + formData["startMinute"] + " " + formData["startMeridiem"];
        formData["endTime"] = formData["endHour"] + ":" + formData["endMinute"] + " " + formData["endMeridiem"];

        var startTime = parseTime(formData["startTime"]);
        var endTime = parseTime(formData["endTime"]);
        var totalDuration = endTime - startTime;

        var breakDuration = document.querySelector('input[name="breakLunchOption"]:checked') ? parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name="breakLunchOption"]:checked').value) : 0;
        var adjustedDuration = totalDuration - breakDuration;

        console.log("Break Duration: " + breakDuration);
        console.log("Total Duration: " + totalDuration);
        console.log("Adjusted Duration: " + adjustedDuration);

        formData["adjustedDuration"] = adjustedDuration;

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
            resetFormState(); // Reset the form state after successful logging
            resolve();
        }).withFailureHandler(function() {
            resetFormState(); // Reset the form state even if logging fails
            reject();
        }).logDataFromSidebar(formData);
    });
}

function resetFormState() {
    document.getElementById('dataForm').reset(); // Reset the form values
    resetCheckboxesAndButton(); // Reset checkboxes and button state
}

function resetCheckboxesAndButton() {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="breakLunchOption"]');
    checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
        checkbox.disabled = false; // Re-enable all checkboxes
        checkbox.checked = false; // Uncheck all checkboxes
        checkbox.closest('.option-label').classList.remove('disabled-checkbox'); // Remove the disabled style
    });

    var logButton = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');
    logButton.disabled = false; // Re-enable the log button
}

        function validateTimeSelection(start, end, selectedBreak) {
            if (!selectedBreak) return true;
            var startTime = parseTime(start);
            var endTime = parseTime(end);
            var totalMinutes = endTime - startTime;
            var breakDuration = parseInt(selectedBreak.value);
            return totalMinutes >= breakDuration;
        }

        function parseTime(timeStr) {
            var parts = timeStr.match(/(\d+):(\d+) (\w+)/);
            var hours = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
            var minutes = parseInt(parts[2], 10);
            var meridian = parts[3];
            if (meridian === 'PM' && hours < 12) hours += 12;
            if (meridian === 'AM' && hours === 12) hours = 0;
            return hours * 60 + minutes;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I probably should have included only relevant snippets :/

Comment: If my understanding of your question is correct, I think that it is required to run the script for putting the value to the protected sheet by the owner of the Spreadsheet. In this case, I thought that this thread might be related to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77345055 But, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.