# Removing protection in a sheet with appscript without having editors permission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know what i ask might be impossible, but idk, maybe someone has the answer, what i want? well I'm working on a sheet, making a form that works with scripts to fill information, but I would like to have the sheet protected for the users who are going to use it so that way they can't damage the form or add data without using the buttons I programmed, but as you may know, to add data even with script you need permission, so if the sheet is protected and you don't have permission it does not let you add any information.

I would like to know if there is a way to remove the protection without having permissions, maybe a way to bypass it, I know how to remove protections via GAS but when not having permission I cant remove it.

I´ve been trying to add a new editor but again, it does not let me touch anything of it without having permissions, so... is there anyway to bypass this or is it impossible? I'm new on GAS and sheets so there is some stuff I still don't know. Thanks for reading my problem :P

Comment: About `I would like to know if there is a way to remove the protection without having permissions, maybe a way to bypass it`, in your situation, when a script can be used, how will you execute the script? I thought that the approach would depend on the method for executing the script. As a sample answer, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77349113). In this case, the script can be executed by checking a checkbox or clicking a button. What do you want to do in your situation? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.