# How to allow to run google script on a protected sheet (in a spreadsheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I need to fill a spreadsheet with information from a forms (that is made with a google app script), but I need the spreadsheet to be protected, so my coworkers won't edit and messed it up.

The problem is that the app script doesn't run if the tab is protected, is there any solution to that?

This is the code I'm using, please consider this is made by chatgpt because I don't know javascript

```
** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function REGISTRODEATIVIDADE() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const formularioSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("FORMULÁRIO");
  const state = formularioSheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  const city = formularioSheet.getRange("C2").getValue();
  const valuesToCopy = formularioSheet.getRange("D2:G2").getValues()[0];

  const targetSheetName = "DADOS " + state;
  const targetSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  if (!targetSheet) return;

  const cityColumn = 3;
  const targetCellRow = findTargetRow(targetSheet, city, cityColumn);

  if (targetCellRow !== -1) {
    const targetCell = targetSheet.getRange(targetCellRow, 4);

    if (targetCell.getValue() === "") {
      targetSheet.getRange(targetCellRow, 4, 1, valuesToCopy.length).setValues([valuesToCopy]);
    } else {
      const newRow = targetCellRow + 1;
      targetSheet.insertRowAfter(targetCellRow);
      const newCell = targetSheet.getRange(newRow, 3);
      newCell.setValue(targetCell.getValue());
      targetSheet.getRange(newRow, 4, 1, valuesToCopy.length).setValues([valuesToCopy]);
      
    
      targetSheet.getRange(targetCellRow, 3, 2, 1).merge();
    }
  }
}

function findTargetRow(sheet, city, cityColumn) {
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][cityColumn - 1] === city) {
      return i + 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

It only works if I remove the protection from the tab, but I need to be protected

And don't think the problem is on the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic process is the same with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77349113). But, from `please consider this is made by chatgpt because I don't know javascript`, I guessed that the modified script might be useful to the questioner. So, I proposed the following modified script.

About your question,

> The problem is that the app script doesn't run if the tab is protected, is there any solution to that?

I think that the answer is yes.

I understand your expected result as follows.

- Your function `REGISTRODEATIVIDADE()` works fine. But, when your function is run in the protected sheet, the script doesn't work. You want to run your function without this error.
- From your question, the protected sheet cannot be written by the users except for the owner of the Spreadsheet.

If you are making users execute `REGISTRODEATIVIDADE()` from a button and a custom menu and the script editor, the script is run as the user who is not the owner of Spreadsheet. In this case, the protected sheet cannot be edited by the script. I think that this is the reason for your current issue.

In order to edit the protected sheet with the script by users who are not the owner of the Spreadsheet, I think that when the script is run as the owner of the Spreadsheet, no error occurs.

In order to achieve this, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

1. The installable OnEdit trigger is used. When the installable OnEdit trigger is used, the script can be run by the owner.
2. The Web Apps is used. When Web Apps is used, the script can be run by the owner.

#### Pattern 1: Use installable OnEdit trigger

In this pattern, the script is run by the owner of the Spreadsheet using a checkbox in a cell. I think that this pattern is simple.

Please do the following flow.

##### 1. Put a checkbox

As a sample situation, please put a checkbox to "A1". And, please unprotect this cell.

By this, when the checkbox is checked, the script is run by the installable OnEdit trigger.

##### 2. Sample script

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet.

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  const { range } = e;
  if (range.getA1Notation() != "A1" || !range.isChecked()) return;
  
  REGISTRODEATIVIDADE(); // This is your function.
  
  range.uncheck();
}
```

##### 3. Install OnEdit trigger

Please install the OnEdit trigger to `installedOnEdit`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#manage_triggers_manually)

##### 4. Testing

When the checkbox of "A1" is checked, `installedOnEdit` is run, and your function `REGISTRODEATIVIDADE()` is called. By this, the script is run by the owner of the Spreadsheet even when the user who is not the owner has checked the checkbox.

#### Pattern 2: Use Web Apps

In this pattern, the script can be run by a button or a custom menu. And, the script is run through the Web Apps. In order to use this, please do the following flow.

##### 1. Deploy Web Apps.

The detailed information can be seen in [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app).

Please set this using the new IDE of the script editor.

1. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "New deployment".
2. Please click "Select type" -> "Web App".
3. Please input the information about the Web App in the fields under "Deployment configuration".
4. Please select **"Me"** for **"Execute as"**.
5. Please select **"Anyone with Google account"** for **"Who has access to the app:"**.
6. Please click "Deploy" button.
7. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "Test deployments".
8. Copy Web Apps URL. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev`. This URL is used with the below script.

##### 2. Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor. And, please set your Web Apps URL to `const webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev";`.

```js
const doGet = _ => main(true);

function main(e) {
  if (!e) {
    const webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev"; // Please set your Web Apps URL.
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(webAppsUrl, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
    return;
  }
  
  REGISTRODEATIVIDADE(); // This is your function.

}

// ### Please don't remove the following comment line.
// DriveApp.getFiles(); // This comment line is used for automatically detecting a scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly". This scope is used for requesting Web Apps.
// ###
```

##### 3. Testing.

If you want to run the script by a button on Spreadsheet, please assign the function `main` to the button. By this, when the button is clicked, your function `REGISTRODEATIVIDADE()` is run through the Web Apps, and the script is run by the owner of Spreadsheet.

If you want to run the script by a custom menu on Spreadsheet, please set the function `main` to the custom menu. By this, when the script is run from the custom menu, your function `REGISTRODEATIVIDADE()` is run through the Web Apps, and the script is run by the owner of Spreadsheet.

#### Note:

The above patterns can be used for executing the script by the owner of the Spreadsheet. Here, this method is used to edit the cells of the protected sheet using a script by the user who is not the owner.

As additional information, in the above patterns, the function `REGISTRODEATIVIDADE()` of the questioner is used. If your function is different, please replace it with your function. As an important point, in this case, it supposes that your function works fine when you directly run the function by the script editor. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)